# seek to time in AVQueuePlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

Can any one help me to seek at particular time in AVQueuePlayer,
I have use this controller to play video in iPhone because i need to play two video at the same time.
But my problem is to navigate in video and jump to at particular time , I am not able to do that.

I Know the method the That is [controller seekToTime:(CMTime)], But it is not moving the video at exact position of the video.

Can any one know the solution and have sample code then please reply me . I am try to solve this problem since last week,

Thanks in advance